# Royal Navy WW2 service records

Tags: england, world-war-2

I have my fathers records of Naval service from the MOD. It makes reference to shore based establishments which accord with photos and information from my father before he’d passed away. Other information he gave reluctantly is also corroborated by other photos records and the MOD material. Two events he recounted in great detail and in one event partially corroborated by photos are not recorded in the MOD record.

Long winded preamble but how accurate are the MOD records?

They don't show or the copies I have don’t show the awards of campaign medals. Theatres of operation or promotions/discipline/trades all of which dad had.

Answer (score 2):

Several years ago, at a FH show, I talked to a member of the MoD Medals office and he admitted that they had terrible problems with some parts of the services not recording the issue of campaign medals.

Details of theatre of operations might be held against the ship or base that someone was allocated to. This would make sense to avoid repetition.

But I would have thought that promotions and trades would be recorded against the individual, so I don't know what's going on there.

Comment: Thank you I know the records were kept during wartime but they appear to lack a lot of detail. I have a photograph of my father marching at the liberation of Norway/return of the King in which he is clearly wearing a Chief Petty Officers uniform which accords with his account but is not reflected in the records. I guess we have to accept  that the records are the bare bones and not definitive answers. An observation that may assist others when requesting and using these records

Comment: I do wonder if it's a possibility that temporary and / or acting ranks were handled locally and didn't make it into the Admiralty records? I would suggest that you try and find expertise in naval records to see if they can shed any light on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

"How accurate are the MOD records?" is a question worth asking, but it may not be the question you want to ask *first*.  It helps to be able to look at records in their historical context, by understanding the agency that created the records, the process that created the records, and the purpose for which the records were created.

Both the United States and the United Kingdom have suffered record loss. In the US, our National Personnel Records Center had a devastating fire in 1973 (an overview can be found at at NARA: [The 1973 Fire, National Personnel Records Center](https://www.archives.gov/personnel-records-center/fire-1973)).

One thing you could try to make up the lack in your father's MOD record is to use the same methodology that NARA's archivists use to reconstruct a burned file. In other words, look for files created by the War Office or outside agencies about the awards of campaign medals and the other events you are interested in.

Start with the TNA's Research Guide [Second World War – an overview](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/second-world-war/) and think about which other record sets might hold information about when service members were promoted, or awarded medals.  Ask questions like:

- Were lists made of service members being promoted, and if so, where might they be held if they were kept and not discarded?
- Where can I find diaries and letters written by service members who were in the same unit?
- How are the details of someone's naval career recorded in [The Navy List](https://data.nls.uk/data/digitised-collections/british-navy-lists/)?

Consider both military and non-military records. Don't neglect historical newspapers, especially [The Gazette](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/).

Search for articles in genealogical publications, FHS journals, Local History society journals, and other published works about Royal Navy service in WW2. As you read these works, ask: What sources did the authors find, and how did they use the information within? Read any bibliographies to see if there are more books or articles that might be helpful to you.

It's disappionting that the MOD record didn't have all the answers you wanted, but that doesn't mean the answers aren't out there.  Look for research guides and finding aids, like The Imperial War Museums' guide [Tracing your Royal Navy Family History](https://www.iwm.org.uk/research/tracing-your-family-history/tracing-your-royal-naval-history) or Simon Fowler's [Tracing Your Naval Ancestors](https://www.pen-and-sword.co.uk/Tracing-Your-Naval-Ancestors-Paperback/p/3270).

Research in the 20th century can be difficult because of privacy restrictions, but you have an advantage in that you're asking about your father's record, and presumably you can provide proof that he is deceased when asked.

Could you ask the MOD to clarify whether or not the record you received was redacted, or if you got a partial file? Can your MP be of assistance if they won't give you a complete record? Might there be other records that you can't order through regular channels, which have to be accessed via the [Freedom of Information Act](https://ttps://www.gov.uk/make-a-freedom-of-information-request)?

If this seems too massive an undertaking, consider hiring a professional who specialises in Royal Navy records from the Second World War, who will be able to put things into context for you and to tell you what information you might be likely to find.  Someone who has looked at many records from the MOD will be more likely to know whether your father's record is typical or atypical.